# Making installation of SQL Express as fast as possible

Tags: windows, performance, installation, sql-server-express, silent-installer

I am silently installing SQL Express with an application but it is taking up to ten minutes to install.  I was wondering if I had the most efficient command line.  All I need is the SQL engine. Here are the current command line parameters:

```
/Q /HIDECONSOLE=1 /ACTION=INSTALL /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS=1 /FEATURES=SQLENGINE /UPDATEENABLED=0 /INSTANCENAME="MyInstance" /ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN=1 /SECURITYMODE=SQL /SKIPRULES=RebootRequiredCheck /SAPWD="MyPassword" /SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE=AUTOMATIC
```

Is there any way to improve it for installation speed since I only need the SQL engine?

Comment: Is this a Windows Installer (MSI)? [There is some information on serverfault.com with regards to how to speed up MSI installs in general](https://serverfault.com/questions/594660/how-can-i-speed-up-msi-package-install-and-uninstall/594661#594661). I am not too keen on any of the options, but maybe have a quick look.

Comment: No, it is the executable.  Would the MSI be faster?

Answer (score 1):

10 minutes isn't all that bad. It probably depends more on the server you're installing on's specs than any of the options for unattended install.

I don't think there are any other options which will speed it up, unless you want to count post-installation configuration towards the time of the overall install.

All of the available options are detailed on the page [Install SQL Server from the Command Prompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-from-the-command-prompt?view=sql-server-2017) in the MS documentation.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to suppress it trying to install SQL Agent (which it installs Disabled anyway). However, I can't see a way to suppress that. Probably would not save much time anyway.

Comment: Yeah AFAIK you can't remove that from the install